# dynamically create an array from a json

Tags: angularjs, json, list, casting

Assuming I have a REST that gives me back this json format:

```
{
  "data": {
    "result": [
      {
        "dispatch_type": "PDO",
        "distribution_code": "foo"
      },
       {
        "dispatch_type": "PNO",
        "distribution_code": "foo"
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": []
}
```

and assuming I want to add all dispatch_type in a select input that is declared this way:

```
 <select ng-model="dispatchType"
                        ng-options="item as (item | uppercase) for item in searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType"
                        class="form-control" id="dispatchType">
                        <option value="">*</option>
                    </select>
```

with this js:

```
DispatcherFilterFactory.paramsMock().then(function(response) {
                            var result = response.data.result;
                            $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType = result.dispatch_type ;

                        });
```

how should i set the cycle that parse the object to an array so i can use the select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get an array of `"dispatch_type"`

```
DispatcherFilterFactory.paramsMock().then(function(response) {
  var result = {};
  result.dispatch_type = response.data.result.map(function (row) {
    return row.dispatch_type;
  });
  $scope.searchFilterDispatcher.dispatchType = result.dispatch_type;
});
```